# Как деплоить код на частный git-сервер на VPS?

Tags: git

Хочу перенести разработку с удалённого сервера на свой компьютер и разрабатывать всё в Docker-контейнере. А какой GUI использовать для деплоя кода? GitHub Desktop позволяет выкатывать код только на GitHub.

Comment: `jenkins` можно настроить на деплой с репозитория

Comment: Что такое деплой на git-сервер? Лично я с git-сервером умею только push и pull, а про деплой никогда не слышал

Comment: @andreymal скомпилировать серверный код на TypeScript, собрать клиент и отправить готовый код на VPS.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin ну это к git-серверу прямого отношения не имеет, это CI сам забирает код откуда хочет

Comment: @andreymal для CI/CD можно использовать Docker?

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin да, но лично я с CI/CD работал мало и более конкретно не отвечу